# Python App Won't Open (Built with py2app)

Tags: python, macos, user-interface, wxpython, py2app

Using wxPython and building it with py2app, I tried to build a barebones basic gui application.  When I open it however, the dock just stutters as if it were going to open something, then it doesn't.  Any idea why?

I am running OS X 10.10.2 and python 2.7.9 and wxPython 3.0.2.0 osx-cocoa (classic)

```
import wx

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(400,200))

        #Creating the menu
        filemenu = wx.Menu()
        filemenu.Append(wx.ID_ABOUT, "&About", " This is the about panel.")
        filemenu.AppendSeparator()
        filemenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, "E&xit", " Terminate the program")

        #Adding the menu bar
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menuBar.Append(filemenu, "&File")
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)

        self.Show(True)

app = wx.App(False)
frame = MainFrame(None, "Hello World")
app.MainLoop()
```

And the setup.py file looks like

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['sample.py'] #main file of your app
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True,
    'site_packages': True,
    'arch': 'i386',
    'plist': {
        'CFBundleName': 'GUI Sample App',
        'CFBundleShortVersionString':'1.0.0',
        'CFBundleVersion': '1.0.0',
        'CFBundleIdentifier':'com.cclloyd.guisample',
        'NSHumanReadableCopyright': '@ cclloyd 2015',
        'CFBundleDevelopmentRegion': 'English',
    },
}
setup(
      app=APP,
      data_files=DATA_FILES,
      options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
      setup_requires=['py2app'],
 )
```

Comment: You sample seems to be working fine for me.  Check if your py2app and its dependencies are up to date. You may also want to try running `YourApp.app/Contents/MacOS/YourApp` from a command line to see if there are any exceptions raised in the bootstrap or startup code, such as if something is not getting bundled.